# (Editable) Landscape table in portrait document (with footer and header) in Word 2013

Tags: ms-word, landscape, word-2013

How  can I do this? **Insert** a landscape table into a portrait document with footer and header, **without** resorting to "cheap" solutions (images, pdf, excel, etc)? I'm using Word 2013 and I need the table to be **editable** (track changes enabled), and I also have to use the "repeat header row" option.

Comment: If you want to do this programmatically, please post the code you've tried. If you want to do this using native Microsoft Word commands, please post your question on [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a section break before and after the table, so the sections before and after can be potrait, and the intervening section containing your table can be set to landscape.

You can do this programmatically, or via Word's UI.